# How to prove the fact that a function with vanishing derivative must be a constant?

Tags: derivatives

Does the proof involve using the mean value theorem and the Rolle's theorem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can prove this with the mean value theorem:

Suppose that $f$ is non-constant.  Then there exist $a< b$ with $f(a) \neq f(b)$.  It follows that $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \neq 0$.  However, by the mean value theorem, there exists some $c$ with $a < c < b$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \neq 0$.

So, if the function is non-constant, then the derivative does not vanish.  Contrapositively: if $f(x)$ has a vanishing derivative (i.e. if $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$), it must be that $f(x)$ is constant.